# Пропорциональное изменение Tile Fill Rect и окна приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть окно приложения, в нем находится:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding RectBrush}" Stretch="UniformToFill">
```

Во ViewModel

```
private Rect _rectOfGrid = new Rect(-1, -1, 40, 40);
RectBrush = new DrawingBrush
  {
    TileMode = TileMode.Tile,
    Viewport = _rectOfGrid,
    ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
    Drawing = new GeometryDrawing
      {
        Geometry = new RectangleGeometry { Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 40) },
        Pen = new Pen { Brush = Brushes.Gray, Thickness = 1 }
      }
  };
```

Есть слайдер, который меняет размер:

```
 _rectOfGrid.Width = GridSize;
 _rectOfGrid.Height = GridSize;
 RectBrush.Viewport = _rectOfGrid;
```

[image: Так выглядит заполненный Rectangle сеткой в режиме Tile]
Картинка на заднем плане растягивается по вертикали

Поверх сетки, также есть ItemsControl, где ItemsPanel это Canvas. Он содержит "токены" которые притягиваются к центру ближайшей ячейки. Также размер токена привязан к значению GridSize (которое задает слайдер).

Задача: При растягивании окна приложения увеличивается картинка. Нужно чтоб размер сетки увеличивался вслед за картинкой, но только при изменении высоты.
Окно может быть прямоугольным, а сетка должна состоять из квадратов.

Попытки: отлавливал увеличение окна и добавлял разницу, но это вообще что-то странное (50 это предыдущее значение окна).

```
_rectOfGrid.Width = GridSize + ((WinHeight / 10 - 50)/2);
_rectOfGrid.Height = GridSize + ((WinHeight / 10 - 50)/2);
```

Что пытаюсь сделать:

1. Пользователь добавляет своё изображение (карту местности)
2. Настраивает размер сетки под данную карту (если сетка есть на самом изображении, тогда нужно или не делать привязку элементов или делать настраиваемую сетку невидимой)
3. Перетаскивает различные элементы на карту, которые привязываются к сетке
4. Существует коллекция карт, каждая со своим размером сетки

vm пока минимальна

1. Коллекция элементов для перетаскивания на карту
2. Коллекция карт
3. Размер ячейки
4. Функция расчета центровки элемента в ячейке

В будущем на всё это дело нужно еще и туман войны наложить с возможностью его стирать

Comment: А сетка у вас как создаётся?

Comment: при помощи DrawingBrush. Потом отсылается во view (OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RectBrush));)

Comment: А почему вообще вы все контролы создаете в vm? Ну и почему вы не рисуете сетку с помощью ItemsControl?

Comment: Почему я создаю DrawingBrush в vm? Просто там находится значение GridSize, которое я регулирую (и от него идет расчет центровки токена). А все остальные контролы находятся во view, в xaml. Задать сетку как набор отдельных квадратов? Как это решит проблему масштабирования? Эти элементы контрола ведь также будут зависеть от размера, который я задам

Comment: Проблема еще в том, что вполне нормальна ситуация, когда сетка помещается не полностью, другими словами не ровное количество квадратов помещается в окно, часть вылезает за пределы

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаю полной картины, но, мне кажется, вы себе придумали проблемы, которых у вас в принципе быть не должно. Если у вас первичен размер ячейки сетки, то рисуем картинку, рисуем сетку с помощью одного или пары ItemsControl, рисуем тайлы с помощью ещё одного ItemsControl (но не с Canvas в качестве панели! Зачем нам считать что-то самостоятельно, если это может посчитать фреймворк?) и помещаем это всё в ScrollViewer. Понадобится лишь пара простых конвертеров.

Comment: В общем если опишете подробнее что у вас есть в vm и что и как должно отображаться в gui, то я попробую написать вам в ответе как бы я это сделал.

Comment: Токены попадают в канвас путем ДрагДропа и далее они также могут перетаскиваться. В теории можно нарисовать сетку отдельными элементами, которые могут содержать токен (кругляш). Только я не понял как сделать ячейки с помощью ItemsControl, на ум приходит только WrapPanel. Поправлю пост сейчас с подробностями.

Comment: Не WrapPanel, а UniformGrid, например